# negative values not showing when using circle function

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pandas-bokeh

I get two different results when I use bokeh`s circle (or`diamond_cross` function) and line function. The line function includes negative values and the circle does not.

Plot with line
[image]
and a plot with diamond_cross
[image]

I want to plot the temperatures for a certain place over a timespan. I have a lot of values therefore I would like to make a scatterplot through bokeh.

I also get the same problem when I use the x function.

In my code below you can change the `diamond_cross` with line and remove the fill_alpha and size then you will probably also get two different graphs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bokeh as bk
import scipy.special

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Quad
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot


df = pd.read_csv('KNMI2.csv', sep=';',
                    usecols= ['YYYYMMDD','Techt', 'YYYY', 'MM', 'D'])


jan= df[df['MM'].isin(['1'])]

source_jan = ColumnDataSource(jan)


p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 800,
           x_range=(0,32), y_range=(-20,20))
p.diamond_cross(x='D', y='Techt', source=source_jan,
         fill_alpha=0.2, size=2)
p.title.text = 'Temperatuur per uur vanaf 1951 tot 2019'
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'januari'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Temperatuur (C)'
show(p)
```

If both the circle/ `diamond_cross` function work the same as the line function then their plots will also show negative values.

Comment: Shockingly, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the the data type of the variable I was trying to plot was string instead of int.

Try using

```
jan = df[df['MM'].isin(['1'])]
jan['Techt'] = jan['Techt'].astype(int)
source_jan = ColumnDataSource(jan)
```